# Java Dynamic Casting in Apache POI

Tags: java, reflection, polymorphism, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to yield Excel reports, and since I would like each column to be compatible with its respective datatype (date, number, integer ...), I made up a static method to return an Object that can be "casted".

Since I am prone to reducing code as much as possible, I chose to do the following:

`String value = resultSet.getString(i);`

`Object castableValue = Engine.formattingValue(value);`

`cell.setCellValue((castableValue.getClass().cast(castableValue)));`

However, this is not accepted at compile time by POI library, while I am sure it would work at run time.

I have to use `if else` for four datatypes (Double, Integer, Calendar, and String).

Any suggestions to achieve this dynamic solution ?

Comment: In the Cell-class there are three overloaded methods called "setCellValue". The compiler needs to know **at compile time**, which of these to call.
`Object.cast()` will return an Object. There is no method accepting a Object, so this can't be done.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to contact the Apache Software Foundation for a possible update of the POI project.

Comment: When setting Date or Double or Integer values, you almost always need to set a CellStyle object to format them as integer, dd/mm/yyyy, % etc. Where's the code that's going to be doing that?

Comment: Yes, I did it. I just don't want to be too much explicit saying, for instance, if (value instanceof Double) cell.setCellValue((Double) value). I just want to take advantage of reflection (dynamic runtime behavior) in Java.